# There are some error in app Gradle for design implementation for version shown in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Error:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1.
>   Open File
> Show Details
>   Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1.
>   Open File
> Show Details
>   Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1.
>   Open File
> Show Details
>   Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1.
>   Open File
> Show Details
>   Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1.
>   Open File
> Show Details

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop your version from `28.0.0-alpha1` to `27.1.1` and see if that solves the problem.